# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'utf8' swift

Tags: swift

I'm receiving the following error when trying to destructure an object:

`Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'utf8'`

Here is the object:

```
{
    ChallengeName = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE";
    ChallengeParameters =     {
        USERNAME = "3bd8b0e1-37c2-4922-8c08-f2903d1a66d5";
        phone = "+13039318012";
    };
    Session = "AYABeLz0aQ7zXFus6wcPLxMd";
}
```

I get the above error when trying to destructure the object with this code:

```
let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
let jsonData = JSON.data(using: .utf8)! // this is where the error occurs
```

Perhaps there is something wrong with my struct?:

```
struct SessionData: Decodable {
    var ChallengeName: String
    var ChallengeParameters: String
    var Session: String
}
```

I

Comment: This is very confusing, what is the type of the "object" you're referring to in the beginning? And what has the struct SessionData got to do with this when you are using JSONSerialization? And why are you trying to convert the result back to Data?

Comment: I forgot, the error occurs because `jsonObject(with:)` returns a value of type `Any` and the compiler has no idea of course how to convert that type to `Data`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(SessionData.self, from: data)
                print(response)
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to call resume otherwise your task will never start